# IOS - Local Notification without user action

Tags: ios

With remote notification is possible to run action without the user interaction, using the :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

}
```

I would like to known if is it possible with local notification

I do not think it is possible though

The app need to make a get to a yahoo stocks and update the user stock in CoreData once a day.

Comment: You mean like background "fetch" execution? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html   In your example, why does the app need to do this in the background and not just refresh whenever the app launches?

Comment: @shim -  I need that because I am not only fetching stocks, and I want to keep a report of every day.

Comment: @Paulw11 - The link point to remote notification. I woud like to do with local notification. The app just do a get call to some urls and get the return and put in the CoreData

Comment: That is background fetch then.

Comment: I just found that. Thanks I will read about that

Answer (score 0):

Read up on background fetch here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html